# Find all filenames that contain whitespace

Tags: c#, linq

I have a big list of filenames, some of which contain whitespace, for example

> "\project summary version 2.xls"

or

> "\production q3.pdf"

These file names are stored in object on string format.

***Q: I would like to be able to query the object with maybe linq and collect all these illegal filenames together?***

Comment: Why can the file names not contain spaces?

Comment: A hint Where + Contains + " " :)

Comment: It is quite similar to creating a search filter for list.

Comment: What does this mean _"are stored in object on string format"_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
List<string> filenames = ...
List<string> filenamesWithSpaces = filenames.Where(f => f.Contains(" ")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options.

One way I'd do this would be to use `string.Split` and check it's result:

```
List<string> filenames = new List<string>(); // fill this list in some way.
var filesResult = filenames.Select(f => new { Filename = f, HasSpaces = f.Split(' ').Count() > 1 });
var filesWithSpaces = filesResult.Where(f => f.HasSpaces);
```